# Wherre can I find the SSMS Schema Definition .xsd File Location?

Tags: xml, xsd, ssms, code-snippets, file-location

I am working on a project and would like to take a look at the .xsd Schema definition file for SSMS Code Snippets. Hoping somebody here could help me out, I know it needs to be somewhere, I just can't seem to find it.

I found the visual studio file location for the SnippetSchema.xsd file, but cannot find the SSMS version of the file, and even tried going to the URL in the snippet example on msdn pasted below.

I also opened and examined the xsd for visual studio, and saw language did not include the SQL attribute required for SSMS. I even did a full search for *.xsd on my primary drive.

I have the latest SSMS and Sql Server installed as well.

Below is an example snippet file from MSDN, thank you for your help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">  
<_locDefinition xmlns="urn:locstudio">  
    <_locDefault _loc="locNone" />  
    <_locTag _loc="locData">Title</_locTag>  
    <_locTag _loc="locData">Description</_locTag>  
    <_locTag _loc="locData">Author</_locTag>  
    <_locTag _loc="locData">ToolTip</_locTag>  
   <_locTag _loc="locData">Default</_locTag>  
</_locDefinition>  
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">  
<Header>  
<Title>TryCatch</Title>  
                        <Shortcut></Shortcut>  
<Description>Example Snippet for Try-Catch.</Description>  
<Author>SQL Server Books Online Example</Author>  
<SnippetTypes>  
                                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>  
</SnippetTypes>  
</Header>  
<Snippet>  
<Declarations>  
                                <Literal>  
                                <ID>CatchCode</ID>  
                                <ToolTip>Code to handle the caught error</ToolTip>  
                                <Default>CatchCode</Default>  
                                </Literal>  
</Declarations>  
<Code Language="SQL"><![CDATA[  
BEGIN TRY  

$selected$ $end$  

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  

$CatchCode$  

END CATCH;  
]]>  
</Code>  
</Snippet>  
</CodeSnippet>  
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon which version of SSMS you have installed. The following is the path for SSMS 17.6.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SQL\Snippets